# Inverse of an upper triangular matrix with all entries 1

Tags: matrices, inverse

I want to find the inverse of a large upper triangular matrix where all its entries are 1.

Is there some trick to it or do I have to compute it using the usual way?

Answer (score 10):

What about
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0&\dots\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0&0&\dots\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0&\dots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 &\dots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots
\end{array}\right]$$

Answer (score 10):

Such a matrix can be written as $I+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent.

Therefore, its inverse is $I-N+N^2-N^3+\cdots$, which is a finite sum because $N$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my explicit answer?

Comment: @GregoryGrant, no, there is not. Mine is just an explanation.

Comment: I see. Suppose $N$ has rank $2$ does this mean $N^3=0$?

Comment: If the matrix is $n \times n$, then $N^n = 0$ and that is the smallest exponent that works. The rank of $N$ is $n-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\eta$ be the $n\times n$ matrices with entries at upper sub-diagonal equal to $1$ and $0$ elsewhere.
Since $\eta^n = 0$, the upper triangular matrix you have can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \eta^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \eta^k = (I_n -\eta)^{-1}$$ The inverse matrix you seek is $I_n - \eta$. i.e. the one given in Grant's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that, for $k\gt1$, the $k$th column minus the $(k-1)$th column is $\mathbf e_k$, which is also the $k$th column of the identity matrix. So, for $k\gt1$ the $k$th column of the inverse must have $1$ in the $k$th row, $-1$ in the $(k-1)$th row, and zeros everywhere else. The first column of the triangular matrix already equals the first column of the identity, so the first column of its inverse is also $(1,0,\dots,0)^T$. Putting this all together, you get $$\pmatrix{1&-1&0&0&0&\dots\\0&1&-1&0&0&\dots\\0&0&1&-1&0&\dots\\0&0&0&1&-1&\dots\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots}$$ just as in [Gregory Grant’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1878511/265466).

Answer (score 2):

lhf, I don't know what you mean by "the usual way," so I will add my two cents to the previous answers, which cover a more or less algebraic point of view. I suppose "the usual way" might mean Gaussian elimination. This is not what is done in practice.

In numerical analysis, to invert a square matrix A one looks for a factorization of $A$ of a special form (I am assuming the setting of numerical analysis, working with finite arithmetic representation of $\mathbb R$. There is computational research for algebraic problems on algebraic fields, but that is a different story). The factorization goes with the name of QR factorization, and it factors $A$ as
$$ A = Q * U ,$$ 
with $Q$ orthogonal, and $U$ upper triangular. This is done because then (if $A^{-1}$ exists):
$$  A^{-1} = U^{-1} * Q^* .$$
Here, the fact that $Q$ is orthogonal iplies $ Q^{-1} = Q^* $, the transposed of $Q$, so inverting $Q$ is an easy problem. Problems that require the inverse of $U$ are solved by backaward elimination, which is how one would do it if working with pencil and paper.

To find $U^{-1}$, solve the system: $U*x = a .$
For example, let's find the inverse of

$$
U = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 12 & -3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

by solving the following system for $x,y,y,w :$
\begin{align}
&x &+ 2y -z& &  &=a\\
&     &y &+12z  &-3w &=b \\
& & &z &-6w &=c \\
& & & & w&=d \\
\end{align}
From the last equation, $ w=d$. Substitute in the previous 3 equations and re-arrange:
\begin{align}
&x + & 2y &-z  &=a\\
& & y & + 12z &=b &+3d\\
& & &z &=c &+6d\\
\end{align}
From the last equation, $z=c+6d$. Substitute in the previous 2 equations and re-arrange:
\begin{align}
&x + & 2y &=a &+c & +6d\\
& & y &=b & -12c &-69d\\
\end{align}
From the last equation, $y=b -12c-69d$. Substituting in the previous equation and simplifying:
\begin{align}
&x &=a -2b +25c +144d .\\
\end{align}
Putting all together:
\begin{align}
x&= a &-2b &+25c &+144d\\
y&= &b &-12c&-69d\\
z&=&&c&+6d \\
w&=&&&d \\
\end{align}

We can read $U^{-1}$ from the las expression:
$$
U^{-1} = \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & -2 & 25 & 144 \\
 0 & 1 & -12 & -69 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$
$$\dots\dots\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

If you look at matrix multiplication as explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1875412/351999), you can pretty much *see* what the inverse in this case. I will give a detailed explanation here, but I would normally go through this in my head.
Let A be the matrix you described, in the case of $n=3$, then we have
$\newcommand{\vek}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$
\begin{align}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &   \\
\vek{a}_1 & \vek{a}_2 & \vek{a}_3 \\
 &  &   \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 &  1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Also let $\vek{e}_j$ denote the canonical base vectors of the three dimensional vector space. If you red the post I linked, you should realise that, calculating the inverse comes down to finding $\vek{\nu}_j$'s such that 
$$
A 
\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &   \\
\vek{\nu}_1 & \vek{\nu}_2 & \vek{\nu}_3 \\
 &  &   \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &   \\
A\vek{\nu}_1 & A\vek{\nu}_2 & A\vek{\nu}_3 \\
 &  &   \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Because then the inverse of $A$ is just the matrix that has the $\vek{\nu}_j$ as column vectors. Since every $\vek{\nu_j}$ gives us a linear combinations of the $\vek{a}_k$'s, we will just try to find linear combinations of the $\vek{a}_k$'s that are equal to $\vek{e}_j$ for $j= 1,2,3$
\begin{align}
\vek{e}_1 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\vek{a}_1 = A
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\vek{e}_2 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\vek{a}_2 - \vek{a}_1 
= A
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\vek{e}_3 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
&= 
\vek{a}_3 - \vek{a}_2 
= A
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
So the inverse turns out to be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &  -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Just as a check, using the calculations we did above, we get
$$
A \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &  -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
A
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} &
A
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} &
A
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ -1 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For $n>3$ you should now be able to see how to get the $\vek{e}_j$'s, using the $\vek{a}_k$'s.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}x+y+z+t&=a\\
y+z+t&=b\\
z+t&=c\\
t&=d,
\end{align}\end{cases}$$

is immediately solved by subtractions

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}x&=a-b\\
y&=b-c\\
z&=c-d\\
t&=d.
\end{align}\end{cases}$$

You can easily construct the inverse (or keep it as an implicit formula).