# Let $T_n$ be the set of all upper triangular matrices of size n having 1 on the main diagonal. Show that if $A \in T_n$ then $A^{-1}\in T_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The approach I am thinking of is examining $AX=I$ and then solving for $X$, but that seems a bit tedious, if I am not missing something. Any help or hints are appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse of an upper triangular matrix with all entries 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878505/inverse-of-an-upper-triangular-matrix-with-all-entries-1)

Comment: @AnneBauval Probably. If $A\in T_n$ then we can say $A= I-B$, where B is nilpotent. According to a theorem in my coursebook, for nilpotent matrices B we have $(I-B)^{-1}=I+C$ where C is also nilpotent. $(I+C)\in T_n$ and we are done. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Not quite ($C$ nilpotent does not imply $I+C\in T_n$), but a correct and shorter proof is in the link above.

Comment: @AnneBauval I guess the top answer but I am not sure where the sum $I-N+N^2-N^3+\cdots$ comes from.

Comment: The problem here seems to be setup in the title, with the entries of upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix $T$ unspecified above the diagonal (unlike the proposed duplicate, @AnneBauval).  The Question in its current form needs editing, so that a complete problem formulation appears in the body of the Question (not in the title alone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the top answer. And if $A=I+N$ with $N^k=0$, then $C:=-N+N^2-N^3+\dots+(-N)^{k-1}$ (which is not only nilpotent but, more precisely, uppertriangular with $0$'s on the diagonal, since $N$ is) satisfies:
$$A(I+C)=AI-AN+AN^2+\dots=I+N-N-N^2+N^2+\dots=I$$
(by [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)) and similarly, $(I+C)A=I.$

Comment: Aha so $C$ Is just a clever construction?

Comment: Aha yes, nothing more!